# Are shared libraries loaded with dlopen automatically closed?

Tags: c, shared-libraries, dlopen, dynamic-loading

If I open a dynamic library using `dlopen` and my program terminates without a corresponding `dlclose`, will the reference count  be decremented? If not, what happens? Will the library remain loaded until the next reboot?

Comment: Er. As far as I know, "loading a library" is something that affects the current program only, so if the program terminates, there is nothing for the library to remain loaded in. Kind of like malloc/free.

Comment: @melpomene That's sort of what I assumed, but I can't find any documentation that confirms this. You'd think it'd easier to find, but it isn't mentioned anywhere.

Comment: A shared library is just a file. Nothing more. And ones you open with dlopen are no different from ones you link with. Run strace on any dynamically linked program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamic loader is a user-space code (ld.so.1 in linux/glibc). It is loaded into userspace of the program you are running, and doesn't interact with other processes. So there is no global reference counters.

There is, however, a way to share code of dynamic libraries between processes. Dynamic loader uses mmap() to load library code in process memory. mmap-ed data of the same library will be shared between all processes that use it (until they write anything to these data pages, this will create their own copy of data using COW). And when your program terminates, all mmap-ed regions are freed. You may consider this a kind of reference counter decrement - your copies of data pages are now released.